# An idiom for using power of position to get things done

Tags: idiom-requests

It is not **nepotism** as nepotism is possible because they use their power and it is *use their power* which I want to replace.

Example situation would be getting into someplace by force, like a concert, restaurant or other event.

Another example would be delaying a plane because they can't make it on time.

The politician often ______ and people aren't pleased.

I need a **verb idiom only**.

Answer (score 3):

**to pull rank**

> to use the power that your position gives you over someone in order to make them do what you want:
>
> *He doesn't have the authority to pull rank on me.*
>   — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-rank)

The politician often *pulls rank* and people aren't pleased.

Answer (score 1):

See **throw one's weight around**.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/throw_one%27s_weight_around)

> To exercise influence or authority, especially to an excessive degree or in an objectionable manner.

Answer (score 1):

To abuse one's power.

[Abuse of power](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/abuse-of-power.html) means:

> The act of using one’s position of power in an abusive way. This can
>   take many forms, such as taking advantage of someone, gaining access
>   to information that shouldn’t be accessible to the public, or just
>   manipulating someone with the ability to punish them if they don’t
>   comply.

[BusinessDictionary.com]

Your example:

> The politician often abuses (overuses) his/her power and people aren't
>   pleased.

Answer (score 0):

***[to boss somebody around](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/boss+around):***

> - to tell someone what to do.
>
>   - *States and communities have complained that they're being bossed around by Washington.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms )